# Java Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I downloaded an android map app and am trying to successfully run the app. When I build and run, I however run into an error here.

```
--my manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shawnbe.mallfinder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MallFinderActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>


//logcat error
08-04 16:55:34.492: E/PackageManager(59): Package com.shawnbe.mallfinder requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
08-04 16:55:34.492: W/PackageManager(59): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.shawnbe.mallfinder.apk



[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] ------------------------------
[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Android Launch!
[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Performing com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity activity launch
[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'MAPAPP1'
[2012-08-04 12:00:34 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Uploading com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-04 12:00:35 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Installing com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.apk...
[2012-08-04 12:00:37 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-08-04 12:00:37 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-08-04 12:00:37 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Are you installing the app on the emulator? If so, make sure you are using AVD that has Google API. If this is on your phone, then your firmware does not have Google Map library, and thus you can't install this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your emulator AVD does not have Google Maps. Create an emulator AVD with a "Target" that has "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" in the name.